# New libraries required Airflow

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am currently using docker-compose up to run my apache airflow image which i get from docker.
However, when I try to run my pythonOperator(python script which contain additional libraries), errors occur when building the airflow.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        AIRFLOW_DEPS: gcp_api
        PYTHON_DEPS: sqlalchemy==1.2.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - FERNET_KEY=jsDPRErfv8Z_eVTnGfF8ywd19j4pyqE3NpdUBA_oRTo=
    volumes:
      - /dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags # My dags files
      - /src:/usr/local/airflow/src # my src files and its the one that contain the new libraries
      # Uncomment to include custom plugins
      # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

The command i use when running docker:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The error messsage I received.

[image]

Could anyone tell me how can I fix this error? How should I install new packages when I want to add more pythonOperators?

Comment: can anyone assist me in this please.

Comment: So a DAG broke because of a missing package right? If the creator of the docker images cannot fix this then you could alternatively create your own image based on the Dockerfile of this image. You should be able to install new packages that way including the one you need. Either alter the dockerfile if provided or use their image as a base (FROM statement)  in your own dockerfile.

Comment: How can I build it? I actually follow the tutorial from this link: https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial

Comment: Since you followed the tutorial, I suggest first to get in contact with the creator of this image (puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1) and write a bugreport. If the creator cannot or won't fix it, follow a tutorial on creating docker images. You will create a Dockerfile and base it on some other image. If you base yours on this image there will be an option to install custom packages on creation which will be persistent in all instances created from this image.

Comment: Also, since the tutorial mentions this specific version (1.10.1) but the repository is already on version 1.10.9, it's worth trying the newest version first.

Comment: Lastly, in the documentation on that page it clearly states "Optionally install Extra Airflow Packages and/or python dependencies at build time :". Follow those steps to install the missing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install in the docker your required libraries, that is quick solution:

Access the container id of airflow worker as root user

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                                        NAMES
c73425b30981        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh work…"   7 hours ago         Up 7 hours             5555/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8793/tcp                 airflow_worker_1
```

`docker exec -it --user root c73 /bin/bash`

Run apt get update
`root@c73425b30981:/usr/local/airflow# apt-get update`

Then install your python libraries
`root@c73425b30981:/usr/local/airflow# pip install Janome`

Then you will be able to use janome library

Comment: Sir, why is it everytime I down and then docker-compose up -d. I need to redo the steps all over again?

Comment: I followed tutorial from here https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial

Comment: This answer is a quick and dirty answer to your problem. It is bad practice to install packages on an instance instead of an image. This is also why you have to repeat these steps every time the container is taken down. The changes in instances are never persistant.

Comment: In fact this is not a good practice but can solve the issue you were facing. To fix this permanently you can do your own docker image and edit yml file with the libraries you want - Try to do your docker image with this link - https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/